# Cannot write bytes broken pipe

Tags: boot, xorg, video, freeze

I can't seem to boot Ubuntu 12.04 on my t-61 Thinkpad. I get the splash screen, then a black screen that reads:

```
Cannot write bytes: broken pipe.
```

Let me first say that originally I had removed `xserver-xorg-video-mach64`(because I have an Intel video card) `xserver-xorg-core`, and other similar packages that I thought were extraneous. After doing this, I would get the black screen but it would say something about Plymouth and freeze. So then I reinstalled all the xserver packages I removed by installing `xserver-xorg-video-all`.

This is when I got the current error message:

```
cannot write bytes: broken pipe
```

Please be verbose with your answers, as I am not that knowledgeable about Linux

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you boot into the [recovery](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)?

Comment: Yes, and sometimes, on normal boot up, it gives the error message or nothing at all, just a grey cursor. Before it gives the black screen, it says one of my drives failed to mount or isn't ready yet; it usually always does this though, and I just wait.

Comment: If it were me, I'd boot into recovery and attempt to run `sudo tasksel` and install another environment to see if that fixes anything, or a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to get the latest kernel which would hopefully fix whatever may be broken.

Comment: Well, I don't think installing a different gui would do anything, as I don't even have console access. When I say their is a grey cursor on a black screen; the cursor isn't blinking its frozen. It is one that is supposed to write a few messages, before the login screen loads

Comment: If you can boot into recovery you should be given access to a shell. If it is not interactive then I'd pop in a livecd to see what you could repair. If the OS is toast then save your data and reinstall.

Comment: What does the error actually mean? And how would uninstalling drivers that don't correspond to my machine's hardware do anything?

Comment: It usually means that it went to converse with another component that is referenced but that component was not there. Thus it broke.  ALSO IMPORTANT TO NOTE: `sudo apt-get update` will fetch *THE LATEST* drivers and such and then when you install you will not be installing a package that currently exists on your system. THIS IS IMPORTANT BECAUSE IF YOU DO NOT HAVE THE LATEST PACKAGES YOU MAY BE REFERENCING SOMETHING THAT NO LONGER EXISTS.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalled the ubuntu desktop, fixed it. It was still a driver issue though, even though I said I reinstalled xserver-xorg-video-all. It had something to do with the dependencies.

Comment: This solution solved my problem .Lot of Thanks Man