# Ubuntu 12.04 - repeated booting problems

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot

I have been having problems with my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installation (dual boot with Windows 7). Whenever I install some update OR if the machine is stuck & I try to do a hard reboot, the OS never boots back and either shows the message :

```
could not write bytes : broken pipe
```

OR shows a black screen with a cursor on top left :

```
_
```

I don't think I have done really wrong with my Ubuntu ( a hard reboot shouldn't break a OS .. everyone does that); just now it happened after I just installed a new copy and rebooted after some steps (see edit).

I want to ask what are the causes of these errors as I want to find a permanent fix to this problem. Can someone suggest how I could diagnose the problem with my machine ?

**Edit**

One thing I would like to add to my question, since I am getting some responses and I need to give accurate description. I forgot to mention, that I tried to compile Android on my machine. That requires the following step (I didn't know it would effect the machine because of my lack of experience - but now I think I need to mention it) :

```
sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
zip curl zlib1g-dev libc6-dev lib32ncurses5-dev ia32-libs \
x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32readline5-dev lib32z-dev \
libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 tofrodos python-markdown \
libxml2-utils xsltproc
```

See [here](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html#installing-required-packages-ubuntu-1204).

When I try to this, it removes a lot of packages related to xserver/xorg, because one these has a dependency; when I try to apt-get that dependency, it removes many packages.
Could this be causing the problem ?
Could someone please try running this ? (I don't have experience with these packages)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/433938/cannot-write-bytes-broken-pipe.

Comment: @Jos It's not a duplicate. I am observing it under different circumstances. Please let me solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is related to the X server. It seems that your configuration was corrupted by your installation of the Android SDK. 
Try the following installation command instead:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential zip curl \
zlib1g-dev libc6-dev lib32ncurses5-dev lib32z1 x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev \
lib32readline-gplv2-dev lib32z-dev libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 \
tofrodos python-markdown libxml2-utils xsltproc
```

Note: some issues remained after that, related to linking of `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so`. Try using `locate to libGL.so` to find your local version of the library, and then creating a symbolic soft link with `ln -s YOURLIB TARGETLIB`.

Answer (score 1):

May the problem cause by nvidia, try by removing nvidia and reinstall with current updates.

Do the following in terminal,

```
$ sudo apt-get purge nvidia-* 
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
```

Comment: I do have Nvidia graphics card. I didn't install anything specific for it yet in Ubuntu. Let me try to run these commands.

Comment: @Jake is my information helpful? if it is accept the answer, It will helpful others may have same problem.

Comment: I am working on it.Its not solved yet.But your answer seems to be leading in the right direction. noleti is taking a look at the problem as well.

Comment: You can see the comments I put in his answer so far

Comment: @Jake ok keep working...

Comment: For now I am accepting noleti's answer, but still your advice was helpful. Thanks for taking the time :)

Comment: @Jake it's ok...

Comment: I did follow your suggestion regarding nvidia, but stil the graphics shows unknown. Do you think this answer is useful: http://askubuntu.com/a/85322/26672, the `mesa-utils` package gave me the xserver problem. Do you know any other way ? Thanks (Sorry not directly related to my question)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15771/discussion-between-a-j-and-jake).